# Use awk to split hundreds of files, have the filename include the original file name plus the column used to split

Tags: awk

I have hundreds of files that look like this:

```
2 300 500
2 1000 1050
3 500 600
```

with hundreds of lines in each file. I want to split by the third column, but then have the output include the original file. That way I can do this to hundreds of files without overwriting and ending up with just one set.

I am splitting using:

```
awk '{print>$3}'
```

This splits the files, but each one gets named `500.txt`, `1050.txt` etc. If the file name is `SRR3.counts`, I would like the files to be `SRR3.500.txt` rather than `500.txt`

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
awk '{p=FILENAME; sub(/\..*/, "", p); print>p"."$3".txt"}' SRR*
```

Comment: I need it to not require manual input of the file name, so it can loop over all of the files

Comment: You expect all the files to have the first part before the first `.` ? Please clarify your post

Comment: Yes. So if I run it on a bunch of files the first one would be named: SRR3.500.txt, then SRR4.500.txt then SRR5.500.txt

Comment: It's all the time beginning with `SRR*` ?

Comment: It is. You know what, your script does produce the desired output. I will just loop over the files to create scripts for each and run them, rather than making the command loop. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The second one almost works, but there is no . between the file name and the numbers. So it comes out SRR3500.txt instead of SRR3.500.txt

Comment: Awesome! If you put quotes around the period it works.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did, and its actually not putting the file name into the output files, I'm not sure why: I have two scripts named split_header.sh and split.sh that look like this:
split_header.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

    #SBATCH --ntasks=3

    #SBATCH --time=10000:00

    #SBATCH --mem=32000mb
```

and split.sh

```
OUT_PFX="$(cut -d '.' -f 1 <<< "$OUT" )"

awk 'FILENAME ~ /^"$OUT"/{p=""$OUT_PFX"."}{print>p$3".txt"}' "$OUT"
```

then I made one for each file:

```
for i in SRR*

do

cat split_header.sh >> $i.sh

printf "\nOUT="$i"\n" >>$i.sh

cat split.sh >>$i.sh

done
```

Answer (score 0):

... or if your files are named **SRRwhatever.somethingElse**:

```sh
awk '
   FNR==1 {root=substr(FILENAME,1, index(FILENAME,".")-1)}
   {out=(root "." $3 ".txt"); print >>out;close(out)}
' SRR*.*
```

Comment: This gives me an error: awk: cmd. line:2:   { out=(root "." $3 ".txt"; print >out;close(out)}
awk: cmd. line:2:                            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2:   { out=(root "." $3 ".txt"; print >out;close(out)}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                                   ^ syntax error

Comment: sorry, fat fingered - fixed.

Comment: this now gives me files with one line, named .500.txt

Comment: my apologies again - should have been more careful testing - fixed.